# getting info after submitting form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

so Im new to php(almost never wrote php code before) I created a website with wordpress and created a form with FormMaker, when Im done submitting the form i want to be able to hook and read the data from the form then parse it into a CRM system

the form isn't contact form 7 and i cant seem to find the action hook to process the data after the form is submitted

Comment: That code you're trying to use only works with the Contact Form 7 plugin. Please [ask the FormMaker team](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/form-maker/) if there's a similar action hook you can use to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure form is creating using contact form 7 plugin.
If yes then use below code.
Hope its working for you.

```
function dorzki_send_lead_to_powerlink( $cf7 ) {

    //check if it is the right form
  if ($cf7->id()==11869)     // get form_id from forms list.
  {  

    $submit = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data   = $submit->get_posted_data();

    if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {

        $api_key = '402253f3-a260-40a7-85d2-dff0d6fae770';
        $api_url = 'https://api.powerlink.co.il/api/record/lead';

        $lead_data = [
            'firstname'      => $data[ 'your-name' ],
            'telephone1'     => $data[ 'your-phone' ],
            'emailaddress1'  => $data[ 'your-mail' ],
            'description'    => $data[ 'your-message' ],
            'leadsourcecode' => 4, // Internet
            'statuscode'     => 2, // First Contact
        ];

        $lead_data = json_encode( $lead_data );

        $response = wp_remote_post( $api_url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type'   => 'application/json',
                'tokenid'        => $api_key,
                'Content-Length' => strlen( $lead_data ),
            ],
            'body'    => $lead_data,
        ] );

        return ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) );

      }
    }
    return false;

}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'dorzki_send_lead_to_powerlink' );
```

Comment: thats the problem, Im using Form Maker plugin and not contact form 7 plugin and i cant seem to find the action hook